# Intellij: No resource identifier found (Using Glowpadview)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I try to program an android app using the GlowPadView library.

Unfortunately the code does not even compile, because Intellij IDEA does not find the resource identifiers of the library:

```
android-apt-compiler: [AlarmApp] C:\Data\Alarmapp\alarmapp\res\layout\wake_up_layout.xml:36: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'directionDescriptions' in package 'com.fima.glowpadview'
android-apt-compiler: [AlarmApp] C:\Data\Alarmapp\alarmapp\res\layout\wake_up_layout.xml:36: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'feedbackCount' in package 'com.fima.glowpadview'
android-apt-compiler: [AlarmApp] C:\Data\Alarmapp\alarmapp\res\layout\wake_up_layout.xml:36: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'glowRadius' in package 'com.fima.glowpadview'
```

etc..

This is the xml-layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:glowpad="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3f2860"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8:00"
        android:textColor="#fa8b60"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/morningEvening"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/my_time"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/my_time"
        android:text="AM"
        android:textColor="#fa8b60"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<com.fima.glowpadview.GlowPadView
    android:id="@+id/glow_pad_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/glowpadview_margin_bottom"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    glowpad:directionDescriptions="@array/snooze_dismiss_direction_descriptions"
    glowpad:feedbackCount="1"
    glowpad:glowRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_glow_radius"
    glowpad:handleDrawable="@drawable/ic_alarm_alert_touch_handle"
    glowpad:innerRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_inner_radius"
    glowpad:outerRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_target_placement_radius"
    glowpad:outerRingDrawable="@drawable/ic_alarm_alert_outerring"
    glowpad:pointDrawable="@drawable/ic_lockscreen_glowdot"
    glowpad:snapMargin="@dimen/glowpadview_snap_margin"
    glowpad:targetDescriptions="@array/snooze_dismiss_descriptions"
    glowpad:targetDrawables="@array/snooze_dismiss_drawables_extra"
    glowpad:vibrationDuration="20" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I suspect I imported the library wrong somehow,but on the other handside, all the classes of the Glowpad library used in my java code do not throw any compiler errors. The library is located in my libs folder.

I simply added the source-folder of the library by going to Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> add Jars or Directories

I also tried changing

```
xmlns:glowpad="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:glowpad="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.fima.glowpadview"
```

with no success.

Do you know where the problem lies?